# Error cross compiling Pion Network Library

Tags: c++, boost, autotools, mingw-w64, pion-net

I am trying to cross compile the Pion Network Library for windows using mingw64..
These are the links where I am getting them both from ( version 5.0.4 of pion)
https://github.com/splunk/pion
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/

I have boost 1.60.0 and the MSYS from

```
**mingw-w64.sourceforge.net --> files --> External binary packages --> MSYS**
```

If you are wondering why I am using 5.0.4 and not the latest one is cause I have tried this also with the latest Pion Library (5.0.7) with a similar result , Pion Network Library can be built using GNU Autotools or Cmake(in 5.0.7).

These are the steps I am trying:

- Open MSYS: where I already have copied the unzipped Pion Package under /home
- run ./autogen.sh
- run ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-pc-windows

**This is some of the last lines in my ouput:**

> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
>
> ./configure: line 20372: AX_COMPILER_VENDOR: command not found
>
> checking for specific CPU architecture... no
>
> checking for debugging... no
>
> checking for plug-ins directory... /usr/local/share/pion/plugins
>
> ./configure: line 20659: syntax error near unexpected token `1.35'
>
> ./configure: line 20659: AX_BOOST_BASE(1.35)

After this it of course crashes and does not finish the configure...

I have tried removing the line with AX_BOOST_BASE, including the brackets inside like so ([1.35]), tried removing the version and parenthesis, setting the BOOST_ROOT path in MSYS, including the --with-boost=/path/to/boost, making sure that the directory of boost is with the right format of boost_1_60_0.

None of the above works.. I am running out of ideas and was wondering if anybody has successfully resolved a problem like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Your `autogen.sh` call did not generated the `configure` properly, as neither `AX_COMPILER_VENDOR` nor `AX_BOOST_BASE` are found.

As far as I can see from the Git repository, the developers have not correctly added an `m4/` directory with those two (and other external macros) to their repository, so it only works on their systems because they already have a copy of those macros somewhere.

The right solution is to find the macros in the [Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) (the `AX_` prefix is the giveaway there), and create a `m4/` directory in the Git repository with those macros (and possibly remove the creation of the dummy directory from `autogen.sh`.

You can also refer to what I wrote about [macro files](https://autotools.io/autoconf/macros.html) in Autotools Mythbuster.